# According to which index a multidimensional list is sorted in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I was just exploring the sort function provided by python in lists. I really got confused in this case:

```
l = [[[1, 2, 3], 
      [2, 3, 4], 
      [0, 1, 2]], 
     [[-1, 2, 3], 
      [0, 3, 4]]]
l.sort()
```

**result**

```
 [[[-1, 2, 3], [0, 3, 4]], [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2]]]
```

On which index does the sorting happens??

Comment: `l.sort()` sorts the list `l`. `l` is a list containing two elements, namely `l[0] = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[0,1,2]]` and `l[1] = [[-1,2,3],[0,3,4]]`. To sort them, we have to determine which one is less than the other. Since both are iterables, we compare their 0th elements: `l[0][0] = [1, 2, 3]` against `l[1][0] = [-1, 2, 3]`. Since both of _these_ are iterables, we again compare their 0th elements: `l[0][0][0] = 1` against `l[1][0][0] = -1`. Since these are integers, we compare them directly. `-1 < 1`, so `l[1[0][0] < l[0][0][0]` so `l[1][0] < l[0][0]` so `l[1] < l[0]` and there you go.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order

Comment: @JohnLaRooy great answer . Thanks a lot it really helped me understand the concept .

Answer (score 1):

The sorting is happening with the 1st elements of the two arrays given (elements with index of 0). In this case, because `[-1,2,3]` would come before `[1,2,3]`, it results in what you have given,